# Super zoom after Ubuntu 16.0 to 18.0 upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zooming, upgrade, resolution, ubuntu-18.04

!,[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmfW3.jpg)

I Upgraded my Laptop from Ubuntu 16.x to Ubuntu 18.4.
After installing the new version it restarted and turned on like this.

I tried zooming out and doesn't work. Does someone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably belongs on askubuntu.com... Looks like a screen magnifier - have any accessibility options turned on, or try turning them off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

I managed to get to Settings-> Universal Access. I just decreased the zoom.